# Cambiar posición del recaptcha

Tags: javascript, html, css, recaptcha

tengo un problema con mi recaptcha, lo que pasa es que tengo un chat que está tapando el recaptcha y lo que necesito hacer es cambiarlo de oposición del lado puesto.

> Este es el chat que tapa el recaptcha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del rechaptcha

```js
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LcKW5MUAAAAAFDEbbeidit-Mp68IWpXBXuHtmuZ"></script>
```

> Este es el código donde tengo unicamente mis css y jg ya que tengo por
>   fragmentos la página.

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-NBX3XM2');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

 <title><?=$title?> | Abacom</title>

 <meta name="description" content="<?=$description?>">

 <link href="<?=base_url()?>images/icon.png" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

 <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>css/stylesheet.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>css/animate.css" >
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>css/rateYo.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/menu/menu.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/datatables/datatables.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/corporate.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/aos/aos.css">
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LcKW5MUAAAAAFDEbbeidit-Mp68IWpXBXuHtmuZ"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
  .card-image{
   background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/270286/pexels-photo-270286.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     width: 100%;
     height: 600px;
     background-position: -300px;
  }
 </style>
 <script type="application/ld+json">
 {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "url": "https://www.abacom.mx",
    "logo": "https://www.abacom.mx/images/Abacom.png",
    "contactPoint": [
   { "@type": "ContactPoint",
     "telephone": "+52 (442) 307 4993",
     "contactType": "Ventas"
   }
    ]
  }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Preloader - style you can find in spinners.css -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <?=$load?>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
 <noscript>
  <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NBX3XM2" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
 </noscript>
 <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

 <!-- Cabeza -->
 <?=$header?>
 <!-- ./Cabeza -->

 <!-- Cuerpo -->
 <div class="container-fluid"><?=$content?></div>
 <!-- ./Cuerpo -->

 <!-- ./Pies -->
 <div><?=$footer?></div>
 <!-- ./Pies -->

 <!-- Modales -->
 <!-- ./Modales -->

 <!-- Archivos JS -->
 <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url()?>js/pooper.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url()?>js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url()?>js/abacomjs2.js"></script>
 <script src="<?=base_url()?>js/rateYo.js"></script>
 <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/menu/menu.min.js"></script>
 <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>
 <!-- <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/swiper.min.js"></script> -->
 <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/custom.min.js"></script>
 <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
 <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/aos/aos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        } );

        // Crear sesion
        $('#btn_crear_sesion').click(function(){
         $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('Abacom/crear_sesion'); ?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#form_login').serialize(),
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data){
                    window.location.replace('<?php echo base_url('Usuario_controller/inicio') ?>');
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var html = '';

                        html += '<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="ti-user"></i> Usuario / Contrase単a incorrecta.'+
                                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>'+
                                '</div>';

                    $('#alert').html(html);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var $zoho=$zoho || {};$zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq || {widgetcode:"323a03d4fc62756882e34a2c27bb028edaade236ab5390ed36ccb617947e9ec8", values:{},ready:function(){}};var d=document;s=d.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.id="zsiqscript";s.defer=true;s.src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget";t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);d.write("<div id='zsiqwidget'></div>");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $zoho=$zoho || {};$zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq || {widgetcode:"323a03d4fc62756882e34a2c27bb028edaade236ab5390ed36ccb617947e9ec8", values:{},ready:function(){}};var d=document;s=d.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.id="zsiqscript";s.defer=true;s.src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget";t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);d.write("<div id='zsiqwidget'></div>");
</script>
    <script>
    AOS.init();
 </script>
 <!-- ./Archivos JS -->
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, podrías aportar algo de código para así dar una visión más completa y que podamos ayudarte. Un saludo!

Comment: Hola. Ese es el JS del recaptcha, no me da otro código. Este es todo el código que me da google pero yo únicamente utilizo el JS, el código restante no lo utilizo.
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=reCAPTCHA_site_key"></script>
  <script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
         ...
      });
  });
  </script>

Comment: Con el script del reCAPTCHA no podemos hacer mucho, debes mostrar en tu código HTML cómo estás ubicando ese script y si le estás aplicando propiedades CSS

Comment: Ya agregue el resto de mi código

Answer (score 0):

Se debe cambiar desde las configuraciones de Sales IQ de zoho, en el bot Widget te sale la opción de posicionamiento del chat, es algo tarde pero puede que a alguien le sirva